# No styling when converting DOCX into PDF with PHPWord

Tags: php, dompdf, phpword, phpoffice

I am trying to convert a DOCX file to PDF with PHPWord. When I execute the script it looks like that some style elements are not converted. In the DOCX file I have one image, two tables with border 1px and hidden borders and I am using Tabs.

When I execute the script I get a PDF file without the image, all the Tabs are replaced with Space and all the tables have a border 3px.

Does someone know why I am missing these styles?

Here is my script:

```
while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($rsSql)){
  $countLines=$countLines+1;
  $templateProcessor->setValue('quantity#'.$countLines, $data2['quantity']);
  $templateProcessor->setValue('name#'.$countLines, $data2['name']);
  $templateProcessor->setValue('price#'.$countLines, "€ " .$data2['price'] ."");
}

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRenderer('./dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath('./dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DOMPDF');

$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Word');
\$templateProcessor->saveAS($temp_file);

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($temp_file); 

$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('result.pdf');  

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='result.pdf'");
readfile("result.pdf");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a look on the source code, it seems that **PHPWord** previously converts the document **into an HTML** representation **before** letting it be saved it into **PDF** by **dompdf**, another converter.

That's what the opened [issue #1139](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1139) confirms, moreover it deals with styles missing:

> The PDF writers being used **are taking in the HTML output**, which also **lacks the styling**. The classes are being defined in the `<style>` tag, but they are just not being used.

Also the [last message](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1139#issuecomment-408407516) adds:

> This still seems to be an issue. html and pdf outputs do not replicate the some styles in docx (header / footers).

Concerning your border problem, another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782160) shows a similar issue in a conversion HTML -> PDF. A [solution](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1139#issuecomment-408407516) was to edit the CSS style, which you obviously cannot perform in your sample code, unless you proceed to pre-convert into HTML.

In conclusion, you may not solve your problem in the short term. If you won't be a part of the dev team, you could **submit bug reports** to them (and not to dompdf, since it's an HTML-to-PDF converter and they are outside the scope). Github lets you to add DOCX files to the issue report.

## **Alternatives**

You could check out a SO question [204860](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204860/best-server-side-net-pdf-editing-library) about **server sides** PDF editing **library**. Below two alternatives, one is free software, the other is closed source and priced.

### LibreOffice

Another way is to use **LibreOffice** in **headless mode** (command line execution without interface):

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf <filename_to_convert>
```

A **PHP wrapper** for LibreOffice, **[Office Converter](https://github.com/ncjoes/office-converter)** is also available here if you don't want to bother using libreoffice through `exec()`.

Check if LibreOffice conversion will suit your needs (it may not cover all cases, but be satisfying your scope).

### Aspose

The best converter I ever used at work is **Aspose**, an API covering Documents with Aspose.Words package, Worksheets with Aspose.Cells, Presentations with Aspose.Slides and so on. But it's closed-source and [pretty expensive](https://purchase.aspose.com/pricing) (and you'll [pay for updates](https://purchase.aspose.com/policies/subscriptions) if you want them after your license expiration).

There is a way to use it in PHP through Java (Aspose.[Words](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/Download+and+Configure+Aspose.Words+in+PHP) and Aspose.[Cells](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Download+and+Configure+Aspose.Cells+in+PHP)) or .NET (Aspose.[Words](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Aspose.Words+.NET+for+PHP) same seems to go with Aspose.[Cells](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Aspose.Cells+.NET+for+PHP)).

Comment: Do you know a alternative script that I can use?

Comment: Is there any news here with phpword converting to PDF?

Comment: @user727198, maybe you should check it out in the project GitHub page.

Comment: `libreoffice` is no longer a valid command. If you get an error like this: "'libreoffice' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file", try using `soffice --headless --convert-to pdf <filename_to_convert>`. Works for me with LibreOffice 7.5.4.2.

Comment: @VeryColdAir, I looked in the package build script of the Linux distribution I use, and `libreoffice` is a symbolic link to `soffice`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: soffice works fine, but the resulted pdf got square fonts